# How to match the data from one csv file with another csv file and combine them using JavaScript/NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, csv

For example, say I have the following data in 2 different, separate csv files:

population.csv:

```
city        | State         | Population
-----------------------------------------
Seattle     | Washington    | 63269
Birmingham  | Alabama       | 212113
```

temperature.csv:

```
index | city         | JAN | FEB | ANN
-----------------------------------------
0     | Birmingham   | 46  | 53  | 
3     | Juneau       | 19  | 25  | 38
```

How can I combine the corresponding data (based on whether each row is for the same city or not) from these 2 csv files so that my data and the columns are combined to form the following (if there is no overlap, leave those rows blank):

```
index | city         | JAN | FEB | ANN | State      | Population
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
0     | Birmingham   | 46  | 53  |     | Alabama    | 212113
3     | Juneau       | 19  | 25  | 38  |            |
      | Seattle      |     |     |     | Washington | 63269
```

So far, what I came up with is (time complexity = O(n^2)):

```
const popRows = await parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/population.csv', 'utf8'), {
    columns: true,
    delimiter: ',',
});

const tempRows = await parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/temperature.csv', 'utf8'), {
    columns: true,
    delimiter: ',',
});

const combinedRows = [];

popRows.forEach(popRow => {
   tempRows.forEach(tempRow => if (popRow.city === tempRow.city) combinedRows.push({...popRow, ...tempRow}))
});
```

Am I on the right track or is there a different way I should be approaching this? Any guidance or links to a similar problem and how they solved it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You could do an initial O(n) pass to create a `Map` object where the key is the city and the value is the popRow value. Then, you can do a single pass of tempRows, checking if the city is found from the map or not. Maybe mark used cities somewhere so that at the end you can output the poprows that didn't match. Fyi, you're basically trying to do an "outer join", in SQL terms.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a reasonable solution for just starting out. However, if you can guarantee that the two sheets have the same number of rows you could reduce this down to a single loop:

```js
const combinedRows = [];

if (popRows.length !== tempRows.length) {
  throw new Error("Population and temperature data must have the same number of rows");
}

const numRows = popRows.length;
for (let i = 0; i < numRows.length; i++) {
  combinedRows.push({ ...popRows[i], ...tempRows[i] });
}
```

If you expect the data to be in the same sort order you can do other validation within the for-loop such as ensuring that `popRows[i].city === tempRows[i].city`. I would agree with @cbr that using a Map is a great solution if you want to supported unordered data.

Comment: but is that going to match up the data - for example, will the Birmingham row in both csv files get combined as one single row?

Comment: Assuming the two data sets are in the same order city wise and of the same length (something your current code already assumes) yes, try it!